# convert a if statement to a swicth

Tags: java, if-statement, switch-statement

Could this program be turned to a switch statement?

```
if (Month * Day == Year){
    System.out.println("The date is magic");
} else {
    System.out.println("The date is not magic");
}
```

Comment: Without many branches, this code is probably better as is.

Comment: Is `Year` a compile-time constant? Or are `Month` and `Day` both compile-time constants? If so, it can be. But if it's just an if/else, you don't gain anything by doing so.

Answer (score 4):

To make a `switch` statement, you need to `constant` expression like :

```
switch (month * day) {
    case 2000:
        System.out.println("The date is magic");
        break;
    default:
        System.out.println("The date is not magic");
}
```

But you cannot use a `variable`, you'll got `constant expression required` at compilation time

```
switch (month * day) {
    case year:
```

---

Also

- `switch` is for multiple comparison, not for only one
- please follow Java naming conventions : `attributes`, `variables`, `parameters`, `method` have to start in lowerCase

Answer (score 1):

```
switch(Month*Day){
 case Year:
     System.out.println("The date is magic");
     break;

  default:
    System.out.println("The date is not magic");
    break;
}
```

Comment: Only if `Year` is a constant known at compile-time.